# What is the best technology to be used to make a server call per millisecond from Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ajax, web, websocket, server

I have a situation where I am going to run a game on webpage.
After every millisecond I will be updating the sprite position on webpage.
The sprite position will be provided by server.

Please suggest best possible ways.

Comment: What you have asked for is likely not possible with ordinary web technology, ordinary web hardware and ordinary web connectivity.  You're asking to receive an update from the server and draw that update 1000 times per second.  If you describe more about the actual architecture of your app and what you're trying to achieve, we might be able to help you identify some alternatives that could still offer an appropriate experience, but would be possible on typical web hardware and in a typical web environment.

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate that. Here is what I am trying to do.
ets take an example of Simple breakout game. In simple swing based application, we just update the frames per millisecond with new coordinates of sprites(Ball, Paddle, Bricks etc..) But if i want to develop the same application on web, keeping the same code base, just replacing the "view" part with HTML. Is there any way to achieve it? or I need to rewrite the whole application handling everything at javascript side?

Comment: Do you have any specific reasons that the position of all the sprites in your Breakout game must be computed on the server and then communicated to the client?  Is there an architectural reason (other than having to write more code) that you can't compute the animation in the browser?  I ask because communicating realtime animation in realtime from server to client and being very responsive to client actions without lag is a hard and complicated task and even then has some limitations.  My son tells me about the limitiations in multi-player XBox games all the time.

Comment: We have already developed an application in swings.
We want it on web. More specifically on web browser.
So reusing the code was only concern.
But yes, I got you point and it makes sense. 
I searched regarding doing these things at client side. So many options available.
Could you have any on your mind that you think is the best way to achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The network connection from my router to the ISP gateway is currently 20ms so updating every ms is possibly not the best strategy.

A somewhat reasonable frame rate is 60 frames / second. So if I were to try this I would probably try and send multiple co-ordinates at once. This assumes you know some of the co-ordinates some number of milliseconds a head of time.

Perhaps providing a little more information about what you're trying to achieve may help.

Comment: Thanks Andrew.
Lets take an example of Simple breakout game.
In simple swing based application, we just update the frames per millisecond with new coordinates of sprites(Ball, Paddle, Bricks etc..)
But if i want to develop the same application on web, keeping the same code base, just replacing the "view" part with HTML.
Is there any way to achieve it? or I need to rewrite the whole application handling everything at javascript side?

Comment: @Abhijit It's hard to tell on SO because we don't know how decoupled your I/O part and the actual game logic are.